# Facebook Page Merge- Lost Password

Tags: facebook-pages, password-recovery

I am running the social media for a travel agency. Our original Facebook page has 90 likes and the email and password associated by the account is unknown to everyone currently on staff. Posts to the facebook wall do not correspond to any known email. Another facebook page was created, which I currently manage, and now I want to merge these two pages. Some people like the incorrect page, and we would like to simplify this matter. I have reported it as a duplicate page and still have not heard any feedback.

Answer (score -1):

you can merge two pages by following these steps,

Before following these steps backup your old data(page content)

1.Go to the Page with more Likes. This is the one that you will be keeping.

2.Go to **Edit** Page

3.Select **Update** Info

4.Go to the **Resources** Tab

5.Click on Request to Merge duplicate Pages
(If you don’t see it use this [link](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=238908726149664) )

6.A dialogue box will show you the Pages you manage that qualify to be merge. Select right Pages.

7.The Page with fewer Likes will be permanently deleted from Facebook and you cannot undo the merge.

Hope it helps

Comment: How does this help if nobody knows the login details to the old page account? And even so, how does one back up old page content before starting?

Comment: great tips but you can only do that if you are the admin of both pages. As I mentioned, we no longer have access to the other page within the company. Any ideas?